# How can I animate a MySQL query count?

Tags: jquery, animation

I am trying to achieve an animated counter, now I have queried the database to count the number of rows, and it outputs the number on a page.

I want to animate that number so that it counts from 0-"value".

I created a simple jquery animation;

```
$('.count').each(function () {
$(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
}, {
    duration: 4000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function (now) {
        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
    }
 });
});
```

And now I am struggling to have this animate the number that appears. the number is the number of users on the website.

```
  <div id="users"
```

is there a way I can have the animation animate from 0 to the ID users (ID loads the mysql query count). lets say for examples sake the number of rows is 20. This is probably very simple but I'm not figuring it out!

(I'm not trying to animate a static number, as more users register the number will increase).

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks, John

Comment: Question seems to be entirely about front-end UI even though the # of users came from the backend.  Should not have the `php` tag in my opinion.

Comment: @BeetleJuice Sorry, I didn't add any tags? perhaps I added the suggested tags by mistake. I will edit them to be more appropriate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're doing probably works, but i dont know exactly what the each is for?

By chance i did this exact same thing some time ago ^^ this is the function i wrote to do it. you should just call this after polling the database and it will update the current number towards the new one.

```
function numberAnimation(id, value) {
    number = $("#"+id).text();

    jQuery({Counter: number}).animate({Counter: value},{
        duration: 500,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function() {
            // What todo on every count
            $("#"+id).html(Math.floor(this.Counter));
        },
        complete: function() {
            $("#"+id).html(Math.floor(this.Counter));
        }
    });
}
```

you would call it like this: `numberAnimation('users',{Count});`

PS. you do need to put a 0 in the div/span first so it has a value to start counting from.

Comment: Wow, I think this is exactly what I'm looking for, I'll do a little work with it and let you know! Thanks for your help man!

Comment: Haha, i was happily surprised when i read the question. Like, I think i have some code for this somewhere :D you can also use `number_format/str_replace` to use this with decimals or to add thousand seperators. (i removed them for your case). let me know if it works for you!

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work properly it either shows the "0" or the output number with no animation, do you have a working fiddle that I could perhaps look at? Thanks so much for your help, I do appreciate it!

Comment: @John107 Sure thing: https://jsfiddle.net/eyeng597/1/ I added a delay on the function call of 1 second

Comment: Ah, perfect thank you so much! however it doesn't seem to be working, I think the problem lies deeper than the code and it's actually my machine that has the issue! I've been agonizing for hours! Your a life saver! I will try to find out whats up with my machine now (in the fiddle you provided it shows either "0" or "10000" with no animation) At least now I have found the problem and I can fix it! Thanks again!

Comment: @John107 highly doubt it's machine. Most likely browser issue, disabling/restricting javascript/jquery. Have you tried using a different browser? also open the console to see if there is any javascript jquery errors. I'm guessing you know how to do this, if not i'd be glad to assist

Comment: Hey, Yeah I meant browser not machine! sorry! Finally got it working and it works perfectly now! Thanks so much for you time and effort! So thankful!

Comment: No problem :) glad to help. If you have another question feel free to tag me in a comment ^^ Also maybe you should change the title of the question to better cover the subject (MySQL has no influence on the question :p) Have a nice day!